# Unable to mount usb drive, but computer sees that it's there.. PNY (MIPS Lemote)

Tags: mount, usb-drive

The computer being used is a Lemote Yeeloong, and the OS is currently Debian Wheezy (mipsel) with no X windows system. So the computer can only be operated with unix commands right now (until I configure an X system).
I plug in the USB, which is formatted with a FAT32 filesystem, and the syslog says to after a few nanoseconds:

```
[sdc] No caching page mode present
[sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

Then I type `mount /dev/sdc` and press ENTER but the computer tells me that it cannot find such a `/dev/sdc` in `/etc/fstab` or `/etc/mtab`.
After which I type `df` to see if the drive shows up anywhere mounted already or represented in /dev somewhere. But I see nothing.

What should I do? Ultimately I am going to put a new filesystem on this thing so that I can use it to netboot. But I am stuck in this place where I am unable to even mount the device.

Answer (score 3):

It's `mount [device] [mountpoint]` **unless** `mountpoint` is mentioned in `/etc/fstab`.  From your question I gather it's not mentioned in `/etc/fstab`, so try

```
mount /dev/sdc /mnt
```

(assuming there's only one partition (use `sdc1` or something similar otherwise) and a `/mnt` directory (create one otherwise).  Maybe you need to tell it what filesystem type to use, e.g. `mount -t vfat /dev/sdc /mnt` for a FAT-filesystem USB drive.)